# Does Cosmos DB provide a possibility for resource locking or key range locks?

Tags: concurrency, transactions, locking, azure-cosmosdb

I have a data model where the next row/document is dependent on the previous. E.g. each operation should add 1 to the previous value:

1. value: 10
2. value: 11
3. value: 12

In the example above when operation number 4 and 5 come at the same time what can happen is that both will read document number 3 and both will then insert a document with value 13. (While I need to have 13 and 14 not depending on concurrency)

I want to make it so that only one operation at a time is permitted. As far as I could find I can lock the update of the same document in Cosmos, but here I do really want to lock reading so that only one update operation at the time should be able to execute.

Is it possible to achieve something like that in Cosmos? It is acceptable to lock the whole "partition" so that only one write/update operation can be executed (ideally reads should be allowed).

Comment: The only locking mechanism I know about is the `etag`. You could create a stored procedure that performs the update on the next document and an empty update on the original with both checking the `etag` using an `if-match`. The stored procedure will make it one transaction so it'll revert all changes if it fails. The empty update will make no changes to the document, but will give it a new `etag` which will act as a read lock. It does waste a good amount of RU as even an empty update acts like a full replace.

Comment: Yes, that may be a solution though it's a bit hackish :) Should be very easy to implement though